# CSS fade transition, is it possible to have the child elements opacity 1 while only fading the container?

Tags: css

i have an issue, i am doing some CSS transitions that look a lot like http://jsfiddle.net/1ummhm0t/

The issue is that the text within the container lags, is it possible to have the text opacity 1 as soon as the animation is triggered, and only doing the transition on the container element?

If so, what would i have to do to achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">abc</a>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

div {
 background-color: green;   
}

.container {
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden:
    display: none;
    background: gray;
}

a {
    color: white;
}

div:hover .container {
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
    animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Opacity of the parent affects all child elements too...so, not really possible. What are you trying to do? Something with bg color perhaps?

Comment: Trying to mimic what they are doing in this menu: http://deluxlife.dk

They are doing it with the keyframe animation, but when i do it, exactly as they do, the text within the menu container "lags" forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f2059cg5/

Is this what you need? You should use `background: rgba` instead of `opacity` for the animation.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    background: rgba(128,128,128,0);
  }

  to {
    background: rgba(128,128,128,1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    background: rgba(128,128,128,0);
  }

  to {
    background: rgba(128,128,128,1);
  }
}

div {
 background-color: green;   
}

.container {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden:
    display: none;
    background: gray;
}

div:hover .container {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
    animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
}

a {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: white;
}

div:hover a {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to animate the `background-color` via the use of `transition` and not `animation`: http://jsfiddle.net/tekwxs07/.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">abc</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    transition: background-color linear 0.5s;
}

.container a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```